# bpftrace doesn’t recognise a syscall argument as negative

Tags: comparison, trace, pid, ebpf

Here is a simple bpftrace script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bpftrace

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_kill
{
  $tpid = args->pid;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", $tpid, $tpid < 0, $tpid >= 0);
}
```

It traces `kill` syscalls, prints the target PID and two additional values: whether it is negative, and whether it is non-negative.

Here is the output that I get:

```
# ./test.bt
Attaching 1 probe...
-1746 0 1
-2202 0 1
4160 0 1
4197 0 1
4197 0 1
-2202 0 1
-1746 0 1
```

Weirdly, both positive and negative pids appear to be positive for the comparison operator.

Just as a sanity, check, if I replace the assignment line with:

```
  $tpid = -10;
```

what I get is exactly what I expect:

```
# ./test.bt
Attaching 1 probe...
-10 1 0
-10 1 0
-10 1 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't your `tpid`s long ints? I get consistent results by printing with `printf("%ld %d %d\n", $tpid, $tpid < 0, $tpid >= 0);`. I can also observe a `1` in the third column if I type `kill -- -12345`.

Comment: Ah no sorry, they're not.

Comment: What kernel version are you running?

Comment: Could you report the output of `grep " pid;" /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_kill/format` (run as root)?

Comment: @pchaigno Linux 5.4.20. The command you asked about reports `field:pid_t pid;        offset:16;      size:8; signed:0;`.

Comment: @Qeole I believe, the argument of this syscall is `pid_t` and it is defined as `int`, i.e. signed 32-bit.

Comment: I took a second look at this and posted an answer below. @kirelagin I think you should open an issue on the bpftrace repository.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, bpftrace assigns a `u64` type to your `$tpid` variable. Yet, according to the tracepoint format doc., `args->pid` should be of type `pid_t`, [or `int`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.5/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/posix_types.h#L28).

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_kill/format
name: sys_enter_kill
ID: 185
format:
    field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;

    field:int __syscall_nr; offset:8;   size:4; signed:1;
    field:pid_t pid;    offset:16;  size:8; signed:0;
    field:int sig;  offset:24;  size:8; signed:0;

print fmt: "pid: 0x%08lx, sig: 0x%08lx", ((unsigned long)(REC->pid)), ((unsigned long)(REC->sig))
```

The bpftrace function that assigns this type is [`TracepointFormatParser::adjust_integer_types()`](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/blob/f5217821697c1350ac65c3fc2a724b2f7909a9f5/src/tracepoint_format_parser.cpp#L217). This change was introduced by commit [`42ce08f`](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/commit/42ce08fc29c017492f75e995b990701c1321b720) to address issue [#124](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/issues/124).

For the above tracepoint description, bpftrace generates the following structure:

```
struct _tracepoint_syscalls_sys_enter_kill
{
  unsigned short common_type;
  unsigned char common_flags;
  unsigned char common_preempt_count;
  int common_pid;
  int __syscall_nr;
  u64 pid;
  s64 sig;
};
```

When it should likely generate:

```
struct _tracepoint_syscalls_sys_enter_kill
{
  unsigned short common_type;
  unsigned char common_flags;
  unsigned char common_preempt_count;
  int common_pid;
  int __syscall_nr;
  u32 pad1;
  pid_t pid;
  u32 pad2;
  int sig;
};
```

bpftrace seems to be confused by the size parameter that doesn't match the type in the above description. All syscall arguments get size 8 (on 64-bit at least), but that doesn't mean all 8 bytes are used. I think it would be worth opening an issue on bpftrace.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange going on with integer types in `bpftrace` (see [#554](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/issues/554), [#772](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/pull/772), [#834](https://github.com/iovisor/bpftrace/pull/834) for details).

It seems that in my case `arg->pids` gets treated as a 64-bit value by default, while it is actually not. So the solution is to explicitly cast it:

```
  $tpid = (int32)args->pid;
```

And now it works as expected:

```
# bpftrace test.bt
Attaching 1 probe...
-2202 1 0
-1746 1 0
-2202 1 0
4160 0 1
4197 0 1
```